# ¿Como extraigo información si la web tiene scrolling infinito?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

quería extraer las url de los artículos que figuran en este apartado de la web "una sección" pero estas secciones tiene un scrolling infinito, que los artículos no se cargan a menos que bajes con el scrolling.

yo selecciono ese apartado del código para registrar pero en el mismo mientras bajas aparecen nuevas "box" que contienen otros productos, como puedo hacer para cargar los demás productos para así poder extraerlos ? estoy utilizando la librería : **BeautifulSoup**

La web es:

> https://www.grid.com.ar/calzado/zapatillas/Hombre?PS=24&map=c,c,specificationFilter_23&O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC

y el apartado que agrega "box" con mas artículos es :

```html
<div id="ResultItems_48370034" class="prateleira vitrine shelf">
```

mientras se baja se van agregando

```
<div class="prateleira vitrine shelf n1colunas">
```

Y aparece esto antes de ser agregado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agregando a esto solo pude acceder a lo que es el contenedor de todo y no puedo extraer los productos porque cada uno tiene una clase distinta.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

#Registro En Pagina
headers = {
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"DNT":"1"
}

url = "https://www.grid.com.ar/calzado/zapatillas/Hombre?PS=24&map=c,c,specificationFilter_23&O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC"

html = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
contenido = html.content
soup = b(contenido,"lxml")

post = soup.find("div",{"class":"prateleira vitrine shelf"})
box = post.findAll("div",{"class":"prateleira vitrine shelf n1colunas"})

for productos in box:
    print(productos)
```

Comment: El contenido se está cargando con peticiones ajax. Puedes utilizar selenium para simular el scroll o bien (teniendo en cuenta cómo se están haciendo las peticiones) construir tú las peticiones GET que se ejecutan y parsear el contenido de las mismas con bs4

Comment: >@CésarGonzález 


Podrías explicármelo mas a detalle ?

Comment: Cuál de las dos opciones? Si te refieres a selenium te remitiría a la documentación del proyecto. Si te refieres a construir las GET puedes echar un vistazo al panel de red de las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador para intentar entender qué está pasando cuando llegas al scroll de la página

Comment: si es por ajax podrías interceptar el success del ajax y usar esa información o  bien hacer las peticiones por separado.

Comment: >@JefferzonBol no entiendo como hacer la petición pero buscare algo relacionado con beautifulsoup y ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Paso a paso

En la propia página tienes un script en js que te indica cómo debe hacerse la carga de los siguientes elementos.

La función `PageClick_18260515` se encarga de mandar la petición y la variable `pagecount_18260515` nos indica el número de páginas que tiene.

Partamos de tu código quitando de momento cosas no necesarias:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re  # lo vamos a usar luego

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "DNT": "1"
}

url = "https://www.grid.com.ar/calzado/zapatillas/Hombre?PS=24&map=c,c,specificationFilter_23&O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC"


html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
contenido = html.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(contenido, "lxml")
```

Navegando por la página puedes ver que el sufijo de esas variables es dinámico, por lo que antes de nada vamos a guardar ese valor en una variable. El elemento `.pager.bottom` tiene como id `PagerBottom_18260515` por lo que podemos buscar un elemento cuyo id empiece con `PagerBottom_`, recuperar su id completo y hacer split para quedarnos con el valor. Todo esto es un poco redundante y no indispensable ya que podríamos buscar directamente el script que contuviese `pagecount_` pero mejor prevenir que curar.

```
pager_string = soup.select_one('div[id^="PagerBottom_"]').attrs['id']
unique_id = pager_string.split('_')[-1]
```

Con este identificador ya podemos hacer la trampa y buscar en los scripts de la página cuál es la url que utiliza para paginar. Lo único que debemos hacer es recuperar las etiquetas script y buscar en el contenido de estas el string `'pagecount_' + unique_id`

```
scripts = soup.select('script')
script = [_.text for _ in scripts if 'pagecount_' + unique_id in _.text][0]
```

Ahora mismo en `script` tendremos algo similar a:

```
var pagecount_18260515;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                pagecount_18260515 = 6;
                $('#PagerTop_18260515').pager({ pagenumber: 1, pagecount: pagecount_18260515, buttonClickCallback: PageClick_18260515 });
                $('#PagerBottom_18260515').pager({ pagenumber: 1, pagecount: pagecount_18260515, buttonClickCallback: PageClick_18260515 });
                if (window.location.hash != '') PageClick_18260515(window.location.hash.replace(/\#/, ''));
            });
            PageClick_18260515 = function(pageclickednumber) {
                window.location.hash = pageclickednumber;
                $('#ResultItems_18260515').load('/buscapagina?fq=C%3a%2f1%2f2%2f&fq=specificationFilter_23%3aHombre&O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC&PS=24&sl=ee7fef4e-00a4-4113-9ff2-316e5d030c40&cc=1&sm=0&PageNumber=' + pageclickednumber,
                    function() {
                        $('#PagerTop_18260515').pager({ pagenumber: pageclickednumber, pagecount: pagecount_18260515, buttonClickCallback: PageClick_18260515 });
                        $('#PagerBottom_18260515').pager({ pagenumber: pageclickednumber, pagecount: pagecount_18260515, buttonClickCallback: PageClick_18260515 });
                    bindQuickView();
                });
            }
```

Y en el contenido de ese script ya tenemos la URL con el token válido que nos permite recuperar los elementos paginados junto con el número de páginas.

Podemos por ejemplo hacer un split por los saltos de línea y quedarnos por un lado con la línea que tenga la asignación de la variable `pagecount_18260515` y la de la URL, que contiene `/buscapagina?`:

```
pagecount_line = [_.strip() for _ in lineas if 'pagecount_' + unique_id + ' =' in _][0]
# saquemos el número de páginas de este string
pagecount = int(re.findall(r'.*=\s([0-9]).*;', pagecount_line)[0])

url_line = [_.strip() for _ in lineas if '/buscapagina?' in _][0]
# saquemos ahora la URL
paged_url = re.findall(r'.*(\/buscapagina\?.*PageNumber=).*', url_line)[0]

# esto por ejemplo nos devolvería:
# /buscapagina?fq=C%3a%2f1%2f2%2f&fq=specificationFilter_23%3aHombre&O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC&PS=24&sl=ee7fef4e-00a4-4113-9ff2-316e5d030c40&cc=1&sm=0&PageNumber=' + pageclickednumber,
```

Con todo esto ya tenemos la URL que tenemos que consume la web via AJAX con todos los parámetros necesarios y el número de páginas, por lo que sólo nos queda iterar por cada una de las páginas (por lo que he visto empieza en la página 1, aunque la 0 devuelve resultados vete a saber por qué) y lanzar una petición get para recuperar el contenido que inserta javascript en el contenedor principal:

```
paginas = ''  # creamos una variable vacía
for i in range(pagecount):  # ejecutamos para cada una de las páginas
    url_ajax = f'https://www.grid.com.ar{paged_url}{i+1}'  # creamos la url con dominio, lo recuperado y el número de página
    html_ajax = requests.get(url_ajax, headers=headers)
    soup_ajax = BeautifulSoup(html_ajax.content, "lxml")
    paginas += str(soup_ajax.find('body').contents[0])
```

Y con esto podríamos parsear el contenido de `paginas` directamente con bs4:

```
box = BeautifulSoup(paginas, "lxml").find('body').contents[0]
```

---

### TL;DR:

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es leer la explicación paso a paso antes de copiar y pegar lo que voy a poner al menos para entender lo que propongo, ya que es una aproximación que no es óptima. De hecho lo que pongo aquí es una versión resumida de lo que planteo:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "DNT": "1"
}

url = "https://www.grid.com.ar/calzado/zapatillas/Hombre?PS=24&map=c,c,specificationFilter_23&O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC"

html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "lxml")

unique_id = soup.select_one('div[id^="PagerBottom_"]').attrs['id'].split('_')[-1]
script = [_.text for _ in soup.select('script') if 'pagecount_' + unique_id in _.text][0].split('\n')

pagecount_line = [_.strip() for _ in script if 'pagecount_' + unique_id + ' =' in _][0]
pagecount = int(re.findall(r'.*=\s([0-9]).*;', pagecount_line)[0])

url_line = [_.strip() for _ in script if '/buscapagina?' in _][0]
paged_url = re.findall(r'.*(\/buscapagina\?.*PageNumber=).*', url_line)[0]

paginas = ''
for i in range(pagecount):
    soup_ajax = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://www.grid.com.ar{paged_url}{i+1}', headers=headers).content, "lxml")
    paginas += str(soup_ajax.find('body').contents[0])

box = BeautifulSoup(paginas, "lxml").find('body').contents[0]
```

O haciendo una función (más simplificado aún):

```
def get_products(url_base):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_base, headers=headers).content, "lxml")
    
    script = [_.text for _ in soup.select('script') if 'pagecount_' in _.text and '/buscapagina?' in _.text][0]
    pagecount = int(re.findall(r'.*pagecount_.*=\s([0-9]).*;', script)[0])
    paged_url = re.findall(r'.*(\/buscapagina\?.*PageNumber=).*', script)[0]
    
    paginas = ''
    for i in range(pagecount):
        soup_ajax = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://www.grid.com.ar{paged_url}{i+1}', headers=headers).content, "lxml")
        paginas += str(soup_ajax.find('body').contents[0])
    
    return BeautifulSoup(paginas, "lxml").find('body').contents[0]


box = get_products(url)
```